# objects sent to react state looping issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a recipe app and I have an api that fetches me recipes based on what i type in. the issue is that whenever i type the search phrase and search, it makes the state super unstable by sending in insane amounts of objects into the state (normally it should be like 10-12 results. These objects are repeat of each other (you can see it in the screenshot i have attached). The code is provided below, can anyone show me why this might be so?[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RecipeDisplay from '../RecipeDisplay/RecipeDisplay';
import Form from '../Form/Form';
import './RecipeUI.css';
import uuid from 'uuid/v4';

export default class RecipeUI extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            food: [ '' ],
            RecipeUI: [ { title: '', thumbnail: '', href: '' } ]
        };
        this.search = this.search.bind(this);
    }

    search(x) {
        this.setState({ food: x });
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        let url = `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${this.state
            .food}&app_id=cf711&app_key=b67d194436b01d1f576aef`;
        fetch(url)
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) =>
                data.hits.map((n) => {
                    let wow = {
                        key: uuid(),
                        title: n.recipe.label,
                        thumbnail: n.recipe.image,
                        href: n.recipe.url
                    };

                    this.setState({ RecipeUI: [ ...this.state.RecipeUI, wow ] });
                    console.log(this.state);
                })
            );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="RecipeUI">
                <div className="RecipeUI-header">
                    <h1>Welcome to the Recipe Fetcher</h1>
                    <Form search={this.search} />
                </div>
                <div className="RecipeUI-RecipeDisplay">
                    {this.state.RecipeUI.map((recipe) => (
                        <RecipeDisplay
                            key={recipe.key}
                            title={recipe.title}
                            thumbnail={recipe.thumbnail}
                            ingredients={recipe.ingredients}
                            href={recipe.href}
                        />
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I would check with `console.log(data.hits)` if that value is an array. Most probably it's `undefined` as the error states.

Comment: Generate ```updatedRecipeUI``` inside the loop and ```setState()``` outside of the loop by ```updatedRecipeUI```.

Comment: @SajeebAhamed can you explain more pls? :)

Comment: Always use `.catch()` even if you know api will return a value. Its a life saver sometimes.

Comment: ComponentDidUpdate is a very frequntly occuring life-cycle. You shouldn't be making API calls in this method. make your `API calls + setState()` inside a onChange or onKeyDown handler, to cut down on repeated fetching..

Comment: If you shared your full code, I can make it work for u.. how about on codesandbox..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try this as you are concatenating the existing items in state with that of the items that are being brought from search results, the state has got lot of data. Assuming you need only the search results in state, here is the code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import RecipeDisplay from '../RecipeDisplay/RecipeDisplay';
    import Form from '../Form/Form';
    import './RecipeUI.css';
    import uuid from 'uuid/v4';

    export default class RecipeUI extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                food: '',
                RecipeUI: []
            };
            this.search = this.search.bind(this);
        }

        search(x) {
            this.setState({ food: x });
        }

        componentDidUpdate() {
    let url = `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${this.state.food}&app_id=cf7165e1&app_key=
    946d6fb34daf4db0f02a86bd47b89433`;
    fetch(url).then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => {
       let tempArr = [];
        data.hits.map((n) => {
            let wow = {
                key: uuid(),
                title: n.recipe.label,
                thumbnail: n.recipe.image,
                href: n.recipe.url
            };
            tempArr.push(wow);
        });
       this.setState({RecipeUI:tempArr})
    });
}

        render() {
            return (
                <div className="RecipeUI">
                    <div className="RecipeUI-header">
                        <h1>Welcome to the Recipe Fetcher</h1>
                        <Form search={this.search} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="RecipeUI-RecipeDisplay">
                        {this.state.RecipeUI.map((recipe) => (
                            <RecipeDisplay
                                key={recipe.key}
                                title={recipe.title}
                                thumbnail={recipe.thumbnail}
                                ingredients={recipe.ingredients}
                                href={recipe.href}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: I understand what you meant about concatenating the existing items in state with that of the items that are being brought from search results, but this doesnt appear to be working buddy

Comment: @Kisho - Is there a problem in rendering or the state itself doesn't contain latest search results?

Comment: meeting this error-https://gyazo.com/d53a511197271bf263f162b1872b8253

Comment: I updated the code a bit, https://www.codepile.net/pile/p6rWZDw9 . right now when console.log(wow) i get these objects- https://gyazo.com/b69fc16abb803629cef05a753b01fdd4. They are exactly what i wanna insert into my state but when i setstate RecipeUI:wow the app breaks down :/ @Sankhavaram Saitulasiram

Comment: @Kisho RecipeUI is an array and wow is an object. In your render method, you are trying to iterate over this.state.RecipeUI and hence the app break down. As you don't run into 'cannot read the map of undefined' error now, you can probably replace the old logic of dumping the wow objects into an array and assigning that back to RecipeUI

Comment: @Kisho - I have updated above code snippet with your componentDidUpdate() method along with changes

Comment: works like a charm now buddy :) Thank you so much for the explanation! Also I get this from the console. Do you know what might be causing it?https://prnt.sc/rm2gqs